# "Завтра нас здесь не будет" - why "нас", not "we"?

Tags: грамматика

In the statement *`"Завтра нас здесь не будет."`* (*"We will not be here tomorrow."*), why use *нас* instead of *мы*? And why the conjugation is on the third person? I would translate it like *"Tomorrow, here will not go to us"*.

Comment: The sentence can be rephrased to use `мы` - "Завтра **мы** здесь не буде**м**

Comment: @Max That doesn't sound very Russian.

Comment: @NikolayErshov in what way? Does it not make sense gramatically? Or does it not flow well?

Comment: @Max That just isn't how you say it. About as strange as "we won't be being here tomorrow".

Comment: @NikolayErshov Ok, you make a point, it doesn't sound as strange to me but I suppose you are correct.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov it sounds totally well to me but has different connotation. Завтра мы здесь не будем means "we will not visit this area/place tomorrow as opposed to our usual habit"

Comment: This is very similar to the recent question: “Это вовсе не сводит на нет тот факт” or “того факта” and the answer of V.V (rules) is excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Нас здесь не будет** is **нас здесь нет** transposed, as a chunk, into the future tense. **Нет** is immutably impersonal, and the so-called negative genitive is a phenomenon you might encounter elsewhere in Russian.

Answer (score 8):

The most literal English translation of *"`Завтра нас здесь не будет`"* is *"`There will be no us here tomorrow`"*. In English such construction looks pretty weird, but in Russian the opposite is true: *"Завтра нас здесь не будет"* is the natural way to say it, while the literal translation *"Завтра мы здесь не будем"* sounds awkward.

Answer (score 1):

*Завтра нас здесь не будет* - passive expression not highlighting the mean of leaving
*Завтра мы уедем отсюда* - active equivalent with *мы*